# Timezone offset is incorrect in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I was trying to find why on one of our windows servers Java application performs tasks one hour earlier than its supposed to.

Printed our time ZoneId offset - its +4 instead of +3. Java version is 1.8, same as other servers. Date and time settings in windows seem to be correct, timezone is +3 as it's supposed to be.

I am not sure what to do - should I work around this in code somehow, or there is timezone settings somewhere in jre, which I can edit.

---

The code I use to see offset:

```
ZoneId def = ZoneId.systemDefault();
System.out.println(def.getRules().toString());
```

Output on bad server is "ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+04:00]".
Must be "ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+03:00]".

Comment: Summer time maybe? Find out by debugging/printing which zones are actually used at runtime.

Comment: Maybe due to `daylight saving time`? [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: We don't have daylight saving. I am just getting zone=ZoneId.of("'), and print zone.getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.now()). It's different on this one server.

Comment: What is the `ZoneId.systemDefault()` in the servers? Do they all have the same default id or does the server that prints a different offset have a different zone id?

Comment: System default is same as the one I use. On all servers daylight savings for now are PT0S, which I understand means no savings. When I print zone.getRules(), it says "currentStandardOffset=+03:00" on correct servers, and "+04:00" for bad one.

Comment: Printed how? What are you doing? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added block to question

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Java on the target server to latest version, and problem is gone.